# item not found in "Find" vba

Tags: vba, excel, find

I'm looking for user ID #s from a list.  However some users no longer exist.  I've tried the `test` method, the `on error go to` method, and `if err.number<> 0 then` method.  I still receive the `Run-time error '91': object variable or with block variable not set`.  The number does not exist on the the list.  Below is my code with a couple of fruitless attempts

```
On Error GoTo errorLn

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
 GoTo errorLn
End If
Cells.Find(What:=uSSO, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Select
```

What other options are there?  Or am I misplacing the lines of "error"? I have tried it before and after the "cells.Find..."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you'll need to restructure it just a little bit. It is not the *best* practice to handle errors with `On Error Resume Next`, but you could try this:

```
On Error Resume Next
Cells.Find(What:=uSSO, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Select

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
 '''Do your error stuff'''
 GoTo errorLn
Else
    Err.Clear
End If
```

Does that work for your situation?

**Source**: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/143988-check-if-value-exists-visual-basic-applications-array.html

Comment: does the "on error resume next" resume the next step in the for loop if i am in a for loop?

Comment: Right - it basically just continues as if all is fine, which is one reason why you need to be careful using it. For a good explanation of different ways to handle errors, check out http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm.

Answer (score 13):

You will want to do something different than have message boxes, presumably.

```
Dim myCell As Range

Set myCell = Cells.Find(What:=uSSO, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If (Not myCell Is Nothing) Then
    MsgBox "something!"

Else
    MsgBox "nothing"
End If
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
Sub Sample1()
    Dim oSht As Worksheet
    Dim uSSO As String
    Dim aCell As Range
    
    On Error GoTo Whoa
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set oSht = Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    '~~> Set User ID here
    uSSO = "User ID"
    
    Set aCell = oSht.Cells.Find(What:=uSSO, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    
    '~~> Check if found or not
    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Value Found in Cell " & aCell.Address
    Else
        MsgBox "Value Not found"
    End If
    
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

I also would recommend reading this link where I have covered `.Find` and `.FindNext`

**Topic: .Find and .FindNext In Excel VBA**

**Link**: https://web.archive.org/web/20160316214709/https://siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/

Comment: you posted this exactly as I started writing the same... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just for posterity, this is how you do it w/out error handling (from: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/519070-visual-basic-applications-error-handling-when-dealing-cells-find.html).

```
Dim rngFound As Range

Set rngFound = Sheets("WhateverSheet").UsedRange.Find(What:="SoughtValue",LookIn:=xlFormulas)

If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
  'you found the value - do whatever
Else
  ' you didn't find the value
End if
```