# Keep getting Error 91 with Excel Find function

Tags: excel, excel-2007, runtime-error, vba

I've tried the suggestions on this site and none seem to work.

In cells C6:Z6, I have dates 01/01/2011 through to 01/12/2012 (in UK date format). I run the following macro:

```
Sub FindDate()

    Range("C6:Z6").Select

    Selection.Find(What:="01/08/2012", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

End Sub
```

and always seem to get Run-time error 91. I've tried using 'Set' to the set the range and that doesn't do it either.

For context, I'm trying to obtain the column number for a preset date (using ActiveCell.Column).

Comment: you could also do it using worksheetfunction.match(...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you simply search for "01/08/2012", you are actually searching for a string. You have to convert it to a date using `CDate`.

Also it is better to check if anything is found using `If Not aCell Is Nothing Then` to avoid any errors. See my post in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972850/item-not-found-in-find-vba/11972933#11972933).

Try this

```
Sub FindDate()
    Dim aCell As Range

    Set aCell = Range("C6:Z6").Find(What:=CDate("01/08/2012"), After:=ActiveCell, _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox aCell.Column
    Else
        MsgBox "Not Found"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Great, it works! Although I found I had to change SearchOrder to 'xlByColumns' and set After to 'Range("C6")' to avoid errors.