# Getting Runtime Error 91

Tags: excel, runtime

I have this find in a loop.  It works fine when there is a "0" but when there  are no more "0" I get Runtime Error 91.  Any thoughts?

```
Cells.Find(What:="0", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
  xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
  , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

Comment: Cells.Find(What:="0", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
      xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
      , SearchFormat:=False).Activate       THIS IS THE CODE IN QUESTION

Comment: Possibly related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984404/keep-getting-error-91-with-excel-find-function

Comment: Also, a quick solution might just be to remove the `.Activate` at the end.  But please give more code as I don't know how you're using `Cells.Find()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do [this](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/519070-visual-basic-applications-error-handling-when-dealing-cells-find.html):

```
Dim rngFound As Range

Set rngFound = Sheets("WhateverSheet").Cells.Find(What:="0", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
  'you found the value - do whatever
Else
  ' you didn't find the value
End if
```

Ah, or just take out the `.Activate` at the end. You want the cell range, not activating it.