# Copying data to worksheet - Object variable or with block variable not set

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I'm having an issue with trying to copy data from one worksheet to another.

I have Combo Boxes that has lists from my sheet heading. I then use the sheet heading s to determine which columns to copy to the new sheet according to the combo box values. It works while editing the form but as soon as i save, close, and open it it complains about "Object variable or with block variable not set"

```
Public Sub ExportButton_Click()
    If FileNameTxt.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please choose a file name"
        WinOSBtn.Value = False
        ExportButton.Locked = True
        ExportButton.BackColor = RGB(250, 250, 250)
        ExportButton.ForeColor = RGB(220, 220, 220)
        FileNameTxt.SetFocus
    Else
        ExportButton.Locked = False
        ExportButton.BackColor = RGB(241, 241, 241)
        ExportButton.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End If

    Dim historyWks As Worksheet
    Dim newWB As Workbook
    Set historyWks = Worksheets("NameList")

     'Create ranges for each ComboBox
    Dim CBA   As Range
    Set CBA = Range("A1:AM1").Find(ComboBoxA.Value)
    Dim CBB   As Range
    Set CBB = Range("A1:AM1").Find(ComboBoxB.Value)
    Dim CBC   As Range
    Set CBC = Range("A1:AM1").Find(ComboBoxC.Value)
    Dim CBD   As Range
    Set CBD = Range("A1:AM1").Find(ComboBoxD.Value)
    Dim CBE   As Range
    Set CBE = Range("A1:AM1").Find(ComboBoxE.Value)
    Dim CBF   As Range
    Set CBF = Range("A1:AM1").Find(ComboBoxF.Value)
    Dim CBG   As Range
    Set CBG = Range("A1:AM1").Find(ComboBoxG.Value)
    Dim CBH   As Range
    Set CBH = Range("A1:AM1").Find(ComboBoxH.Value)
    Dim CBI   As Range
    Set CBI = Range("A1:AM1").Find(ComboBoxI.Value)
    Dim CBJ   As Range
    Set CBJ = Range("A1:AM1").Find(ComboBoxJ.Value)
    Dim CBK   As Range
    Set CBK = Range("A1:AM1").Find(ComboBoxK.Value)
    Dim CBL   As Range
    Set CBL = Range("A1:AM1").Find(ComboBoxL.Value)
    Dim CBM   As Range
    Set CBM = Range("A1:AM1").Find(ComboBoxM.Value)
    Dim CBN   As Range
    Set CBN = Range("A1:AM1").Find(ComboBoxN.Value)
    Dim CBO   As Range
    Set CBO = Range("A1:AM1").Find(ComboBoxO.Value)
    Dim CBP   As Range
    Set CBP = Range("A1:AM1").Find(ComboBoxP.Value)
    Dim CBQ   As Range
    Set CBQ = Range("A1:AM1").Find(ComboBoxQ.Value)
    Dim CBR   As Range
    Set CBR = Range("A1:AM1").Find(ComboBoxR.Value)
    Dim CBS   As Range
    Set CBS = Range("A1:AM1").Find(ComboBoxS.Value)
    Dim CBT   As Range
    Set CBT = Range("A1:AM1").Find(ComboBoxT.Value)
    Dim CBU   As Range
    Set CBU = Range("A1:AM1").Find(ComboBoxU.Value)

     'Prompts for a file name
    If FileNameTxt.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please choose a file name"
    Else


         'Add a new workbook with a file name
        Workbooks.Add
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FileNameTxt.Value & ".xls"
         'ActiveWorkbook.Close
        Workbooks.Open (FileNameTxt.Value & ".xls")
        Set newWB = Workbooks(FileNameTxt.Value & ".xls")

        historyWks.Activate
        With historyWks

            If ComboBoxA <> "" Then
                Range(CBA, CBA.End(xlDown)).Copy '***The error starts here and indecates that CBA=Nothing
                                                 'CBA.End(xlDown)=Object variable* or With block variable not set
                newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If

            If ComboBoxB <> "" Then
                Range(CBB, CBB.End(xlDown)).Copy
                newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
            If ComboBoxC <> "" Then
                Range(CBC, CBC.End(xlDown)).Copy
                newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
            If ComboBoxD <> "" Then
                Range(CBD, CBD.End(xlDown)).Copy
                newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
            If ComboBoxE <> "" Then
                Range(CBE, CBE.End(xlDown)).Copy
                newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
            If ComboBoxF <> "" Then
                Range(CBF, CBF.End(xlDown)).Copy
                newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
            If ComboBoxG <> "" Then
                Range(CBG, CBG.End(xlDown)).Copy
                newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
            If ComboBoxH <> "" Then
                Range(CBH, CBH.End(xlDown)).Copy
                newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
            If ComboBoxI <> "" Then
                Range(CBI, CBI.End(xlDown)).Copy
                newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
            If ComboBoxJ <> "" Then
                Range(CBJ, CBJ.End(xlDown)).Copy
                newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
            If ComboBoxK <> "" Then
                Range(CBK, CBK.End(xlDown)).Copy
                newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
            If ComboBoxL <> "" Then
                Range(CBL, CBL.End(xlDown)).Copy
                newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
            If ComboBoxM <> "" Then
                Range(CBM, CBM.End(xlDown)).Copy
                newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("M1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("M1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
            If ComboBoxN <> "" Then
                Range(CBN, CBN.End(xlDown)).Copy
                newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("N1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("N1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
            If ComboBoxO <> "" Then
                Range(CBO, CBO.End(xlDown)).Copy
                newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("O1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("O1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
            If ComboBoxP <> "" Then
                Range(CBP, CBP.End(xlDown)).Copy
                newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("P1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("P1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
            If ComboBoxQ <> "" Then
                Range(CBQ, CBQ.End(xlDown)).Copy
                newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Q1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Q1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
            If ComboBoxR <> "" Then
                Range(CBR, CBR.End(xlDown)).Copy
                newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("R1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("R1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
            If ComboBoxS <> "" Then
                Range(CBS, CBS.End(xlDown)).Copy
                newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("S1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("S1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
            If ComboBoxT <> "" Then
                Range(CBT, CBT.End(xlDown)).Copy
                newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("T1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("T1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
            If ComboBoxU <> "" Then
                Range(CBU, CBU.End(xlDown)).Copy
                newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("U1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("U1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
        End With

    End If

    ExportForm.Hide

    Dim i     As Long

    i = MsgBox("Export another?", vbOKCancel)
    If i = vbOK Then
        ExportForm.Show
        If i = vbCancel Then Unload ExportForm
    End If
End Sub
```

I have been searching through the forums but i'm still struggling. I'm sure that there is a smarter way to do all of this, but i'll get there. Any help with getting the error sorted out will be so great!

Comment: `.Find` returns `Nothing` if there isn't a match.  You need to test the return value ***every time you call .Find*** before using the result.  Also, you should fully qualify all your  `Range` calls instead of using `Activate` and the globals.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep getting Error 91 with Excel Find function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984404/keep-getting-error-91-with-excel-find-function) and countless similar questions.

Comment: @Jakes Van Niekerk you have ~ 21 ! `ComboBox`es, and your code repeats itself for each one. you need to have a `Function` or better yet a `Class` to handle the `ComboBox` events, it will shorten and clarify your code

Comment: @Comintern, I have now defined the range better `Set CBX = historyWks.Range("A1:AM1").Find(ComboBoxX.Value)`. This seems to do the trick now thanks so much.

Comment: @ShaiRado yea i was sure that there was a smarter way to do it ;-) Its pretty cool learning how to do so.

Comment: @Jakes Van Niekerk  try my code below, see if it works for you as you intended

Answer (score 1):

you define CBA like YourWorkbookName.sheets(yourSheetName).Range("A1:AM1").find(ComboBoxA.Value)
I think run this without error.

Comment: Yea i've had to define the range better

Comment: Because you create a new workbook you have to define CBA like above...if you do not add new workbook, you was right...You can handle range when you don't change both your workbook and your sheet.

Answer (score 1):

With a little refactoring your code can be shorter (and more robust)

```
Public Sub ExportButton_Click()

    Dim historyWks As Worksheet
    Dim newWB As Workbook, newSht As Worksheet, i As Long
    Dim cb, f As Range

    Set historyWks = Worksheets("NameList")

    If FileNameTxt.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please choose a file name"
        WinOSBtn.Value = False
        ExportButton.Locked = True
        ExportButton.BackColor = RGB(250, 250, 250)
        ExportButton.ForeColor = RGB(220, 220, 220)
        FileNameTxt.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    Else
        ExportButton.Locked = False
        ExportButton.BackColor = RGB(241, 241, 241)
        ExportButton.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End If

     'Add a new workbook with a file name
    Set newWB = Workbooks.Add()
    newWB.SaveAs Filename:=FileNameTxt.Value & ".xls"
    Set newSht = newWB.Sheets(1)

    For i = 1 To 21

        Set cb = Me.Controls("ComboBox" & Chr(64 + i))

        If Len(cb.Value) > 0 Then
            'always worth specifiying to check the complete value....
            Set f = historyWks.Range("A1:AM1").Find(cb.Value, lookat:=xlWhole)

            If Not f Is Nothing Then
                'located the header - copy over
                With historyWks
                    .Range(f, .Cells(.Rows.Count, f.Column).End(xlUp)).Copy
                End With
                With newSht.Cells(1, i)
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                End With
            End If

        End If
    Next i

    'rest of code here...

End Sub
```

Comment: you have `ComboBoxA`  in `Set f = historyWks.Range("A1:AM1").Find(ComboBoxA.Value, lookat:=xlWhole)` , don't you need to modify it for each ComboBox ?

Comment: @Tim Williams, That looks so much better. I'm trying this now.

Comment: How would this work for the rest rest of the combo boxes?

Comment: @TimWilliams I know we are not on Code Review here, but is my answer above using a `Class` realy helps in any way ?

Comment: @ShaiRado - I would probably not use a class here unless I needed to handle events from the comboboxes, or there was some other (maybe more complex) behavior which would benefit from being abstracted into a class

Comment: @TimWilliams - Man this is so much more neater! It would save me work the next time around by using this way rather than repeating everything. Below is what I've done. It works other than the form still having the previously entered data but that's fine, i'll just add a clear before the close.

Answer (score 1):

I am using a `Class` to work here (not sure it's realy a better solution) , the name of the class Module is "cFindComboValue"

***cFindComboValue* Class Module Code**

```
Private myfRng          As Range
Public ComboVal         As Variant


Public Property Get fRng() As Range    
    Set fRng = myfRng    
End Property    

Public Property Set fRng(objRng As Range)
    Set myfRng = objRng.Find(ComboVal, LookAt:=xlWhole)    
End Property
```

---

The rest of your code is in the same Sub as yours. In order to avoid the error you are getting, you need to trap the possibility the `Find` method will not find anything, so adding the line `If not FindRng is Nothing` makes sure we are only copying the Successful "Finds".

### *Sub ExportButton* Code

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub ExportButton_Click()

Dim newWB           As Workbook
Dim historyWks      As Worksheet
Dim PasteSht        As Worksheet

Dim Ctl             As Control
Dim FindRng         As cFindComboValue
Dim Col             As Long

' set FindRng as New cFindComboValue (Class)
Set FindRng = New cFindComboValue

Set historyWks = Worksheets("NameList")

' --- Haven't touched this section ---
If FileNameTxt.value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please choose a file name"
    WinOSBtn.value = False
    ExportButton.Locked = True
    ExportButton.BackColor = RGB(250, 250, 250)
    ExportButton.ForeColor = RGB(220, 220, 220)
    FileNameTxt.SetFocus
Else
    ExportButton.Locked = False
    ExportButton.BackColor = RGB(241, 241, 241)
    ExportButton.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End If

'Add a new workbook with a file name
Set newWB = Workbooks.Add()
newWB.SaveAs Filename:=FileNameTxt.value & ".xls"
Set PasteSht = newWB.Sheets("Sheet1") ' kept "Sheet1" as your destination Paste sheet

' reset Paste Column to "A"
Col = 1

' loop through all Controls in User Form
For Each Ctl In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf Ctl Is ComboBox Then ' check if current control is ComboBox
        If Ctl.value <> "" Then

            ' pass the ComboBox value to the Class
            FindRng.ComboVal = Ctl.value
            ' set the FindRange property of the class
            Set FindRng.fRng = historyWks.Range("A1:AM1")

            ' Find method was Successful
            If Not FindRng.fRng Is Nothing Then                
                With historyWks
                    ' copy from FindRng untill last row in that column , "pass" the empty cells in the middle
                    .Range(FindRng.fRng, .Cells(.Rows.Count, FindRng.fRng.Column).End(xlUp)).Copy
                End With
                With PasteSht.Cells(1, Col)
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                End With

                Col = Col + 1 ' I am moving one Column only if Find was Successful , avoid having empty columns
            End If
        End If

    End If
Next Ctl

' use your original code here
' ....

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the help.

Comment: @JakesVanNiekerk your'e welcome, please mark as answer and upvote

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again @TimWilliams for the help.

This is what i've done:

```
    Public Sub ExportButton_Click()

    Dim inputWks As Worksheet
    Dim historyWks As Worksheet
    Dim newWB As Workbook, newSht As Worksheet, i As Long
    Dim cb, f As Range

    Set historyWks = Worksheets("NameList")
    Set inputWks = Worksheets("UserForm")

    If FileNameTxt.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please choose a file name"
        WinOSBtn.Value = False
        ExportButton.Locked = True
        ExportButton.BackColor = RGB(250, 250, 250)
        ExportButton.ForeColor = RGB(220, 220, 220)
        FileNameTxt.SetFocus
        Exit Sub  '==> Is there a reason why i'm putting this "Exit Sub" here?
    Else
        ExportButton.Locked = False
        ExportButton.BackColor = RGB(241, 241, 241)
        ExportButton.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End If

    'Prompts for a file name
    If FileNameTxt.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please choose a file name"
    Else

    '=====================================================================
    '   Original Worksheet Add
    '=====================================================================
        'Add a new workbook with a file name
        'Workbooks.Add
        'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FileNameTxt.Value & ".xls"
        'ActiveWorkbook.Close
        'Workbooks.Open (FileNameTxt.Value & ".xls")
        'Set newWB = Workbooks(FileNameTxt.Value & ".xls")


      'Test Worksheet Add => Still to test on OSX
     Set newWB = Workbooks.Add()
     newWB.SaveAs Filename:=FileNameTxt.Value & ".xls"
     Set newSht = newWB.Sheets(1)

     For i = 1 To 21

        Set cb = Me.Controls("Combobox" & Chr(64 + i))

        If Len(cb.Value) > 0 Then
            Set f = historyWks.Range("A1:AM1").Find(cb.Value, lookat:=xlWhole)

            If Not f Is Nothing Then
                With historyWks
                    .Range(f, .Cells(.Rows.Count, f.Column).End(xlUp)).Copy
                End With
                With newSht.Cells(1, i)
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                End With
             End If

        End If
    Next i


    ExportForm.Hide

    Dim iMsg As Long

    iMsg = MsgBox("Export Complete", vbOKOnly)
        If i = vbOK Then
        Unload Me

End If
End If
End Sub
```